# AS3 showing a symbol on the cursor

Tags: actionscript-3, cursor, mouse

In my game I'm trying to let appear on the cursor an information box when the cursor is over a symbol. To do this i've created a symbol called "OPP_INFO" that is hidden outside the stage, and added an eventlistener on MOUSE_OVER, What should I put in the function of the eventListener to let the OPP_INFO move ON the cursor and move WITH the cursor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
OPP_INFO.x = stage.mouseX;
OPP_INFO.y = stage.mouseY;
```